# Is it possible to have multiple concurrent coprocesses?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, coprocesses

The *intent* of the test script<sup>1</sup> below is to start an "outer" coprocess (running `seq 3`), read from this coprocess in a `while`-loop, and for each line read, print a line identifying the current iteration of the outer loop, start an "inner" coprocess (also running `seq`, with new arguments), read from this inner coprocess in a nested while loop, and then clean up this inner coprocess.  The nested while loop prints some output for each line it reads from the inner coprocess.

```
#!/bin/bash
# filename: coproctest.sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

coproc OUTER { seq 3; }
SAVED_OUTER_PID="${OUTER_PID}"

exec {OUTER_READER}<&"${OUTER[0]}"
while IFS= read -r -u "${OUTER_READER}" OUTER_INDEX; do

    printf -- '%d\n' "${OUTER_INDEX}"

    START=$(( OUTER_INDEX * 1000000 ))
    FINISH=$(( START + OUTER_INDEX ))

    # (
      coproc INNER { seq "${START}" "${FINISH}"; }
      SAVED_INNER_PID="${INNER_PID}"
      exec {INNER_READER}<&"{INNER[0]}"

      while IFS= read -r -u "${INNER_READER}" INNER_INDEX; do
          printf -- '    %d\n' "${INNER_INDEX}"
      done

      exec {INNER_READER}<&-

      wait "${SAVED_INNER_PID}"
    # )

done
exec {OUTER_READER}<&-
wait "${SAVED_OUTER_PID}"
```

When I run this script, this is the output I get:

```
% ./coproctest.sh
1
./coproctest.sh: line 30: warning: execute_coproc: coproc [12523:OUTER] still exists
./coproctest.sh: line 19: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
./coproctest.sh: line 21: read: : invalid file descriptor specification
./coproctest.sh: line 25: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
2
./coproctest.sh: line 19: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
./coproctest.sh: line 21: read: : invalid file descriptor specification
./coproctest.sh: line 25: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
3
./coproctest.sh: line 19: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
./coproctest.sh: line 21: read: : invalid file descriptor specification
./coproctest.sh: line 25: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
```

I get pretty much the same output if I uncomment the two commented lines.

---

**Q1:** Is it possible to have multiple coprocesses running at the same time?

**Q2:** If so, how should the script above be modified to achieve the desired output?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I've only recently started to work with coprocesses, and there is still a lot I don't understand.  As a result, this script almost certainly contains incorrect, awkward, or unnecessary code.  Please feel free to comment on and/or fix these weaknesses in your responses.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the "BUGS" section at the very end of the `bash` manual:

> There may be only one active coprocess at a time.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1: Is it possible to have multiple coprocesses running at the same time?

On Bash v4 and above (including current v5), officially no, as noted by @Kusalananda.

However, I can tell you that it *might* work despite the warning, but of course no guarantee and YMMV. [See here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-04/msg00056.html) for a bit more insight.

> Q2: If so, how should the script above be modified to achieve the desired output?

It *might* (as per above) work just fine once you fix the:

```bash
exec {INNER_READER}<&"{INNER[0]}"  # <-- lacks the '$' sign for the 'INNER[0]' variable
```

which causes the:

```
./coproctest.sh: line 19: INNER_READER: ambiguous redirect
```

message, and consequently also the:

```
./coproctest.sh: line 21: read: : invalid file descriptor specification
```

message.

It works for me, once fixed that and warning aside.

As for other notes:

- There's no need to duplicate a `coproc`'s file-descriptors, unless you want to pass them to a child process (a sub-shell or a command or script)
- You probably did so because the `seq` command naturally finished quickly, and thus the automatic variables disappeared before you could use them. By doing the way you did, those duplicate file-descriptors will be inherited by all subsequent commands and background processes, which might be undesirable if your co-process actually uses its input pipe and waits for it to be closed in order to exit. So another approach to address that is by a synchronization mechanism, like for instance make your `OUTER` co-process be `{ seq 3; exec >&-; read; }`, and then when you've consumed its input from the main script do e.g. `echo >&${OUTER[1]}; wait "${OUTER_PID}"` to let the co-process's `read` proceed then `wait` for it. Note that it is not guaranteed that the `wait` will execute before the `$OUTER_PID` variable disappears: in such case you can just mute the warning message (or ignore it altogether) and perhaps force a success status with an `|| true`
- As a personal side-note I can tell you that, if you are really determined in having multiple co-processes simultaneously, you might re-implement a *rough* equivalent of `coproc` using Bash v3 syntax over background processes plus `mkfifo` named-FIFOs, and on Linux also with a trick with Process Substitutions instead of `mkfifo`s. With Bash v4 syntax it can be less complicated, but still a challenging exercise.